# Redis: finding keys that match some pattern

Tags: redis

I want to get from redis all the keys that the number of elements in their list
(Each value is a list type) has more than x items?
How do I do that?
Any simple way or just have to use lua? if lua - how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve that, each with its own pros and cons. The first decision you have to make is whether you want to have the answer to your query pre-prepared or computed ad-hoc.

For pre-prepared, you'll have to maintain an index of the lists by length. For ad-hoc, you'll have to scan all the lists and get their lengths at runtime.

Assuming you are trying to implement an ad-hoc query, a server-side Lua script is a good choice if you already know how. If not, you can either learn it (https://redis.io/commands/eval) or use a regular Redis client in your language of choosing.